# The elements of the page do not load when currentozo in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2

Well I have a side menu app where the first page is home, and it loads elements as soon as the user enters the app. I'm using Ionic 2 and the communication is being done via socket. One detail is that the elements do not load when I update, but when I click the menu button and I get back the elements load, can anyone help me?

Follows component code:

```
export class HomePage {
  eventsList: Event [];

  constructor (
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public eventService: EventService, 
    public platform: Platform){} 

  ionViewDidLoad () { 
    console.info ('HomePage initializated');

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.eventService
      .getAllEvents()
      .subscribe(
        events => { 
          this.eventsList = events;
          console.log(events);
        },  
        err => console.log("ERROR!", err))
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: can you add the service please.

Answer (score 0):

When you push a new page you need to unsubscribe to the subscription, if not you will have memory leaks. So please rembember to always unsubscribe to a subscription.

In the following code I unsubscribe when the page get destroy.

```
export class HomePage implements OnDestroy {
  eventsList: Event[];
  destroy$ : Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public eventService: EventService, 
    public platform: Platform){}

  ionViewDidLoad () { 
    console.info ('HomePage initializated');

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.eventService
      .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      .getAllEvents()
      .subscribe(
        events => { 
          this.eventsList = events;
          console.log(events);
        },  
        err => console.log("ERROR!", err))
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```